# Is the space of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ separable/compact with respect to the topology of uniform convergence in compact sets?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, compactness, separable-spaces

Consider the space of continuous functions $C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$, equipped with the metric
$$ d(f,g) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{\sup_{x \in [-n,n]} |f(x)-g(x)|}{1 + \sup_{x \in [-n,n]} |f(x)-g(x)|} . $$

The topology induced by this metric should be the topology of uniform convergence in compact sets.

This space is complete.

1. Is it separable?
2. Is it compact?

EDIT: It's not a Banach space, since the metric $d$ does not induce a norm.

Comment: It is comnplete, but not Banach, since there is no norm. You have a countable family of seminorms $\{\|\cdot\|_n:\, n\in\Bbb N\}$, where $\|f\|_n:=\max\{|f(x):\, x\in[-n,n]\}$.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post

Comment: @TitoEliatron you'd also need an argument why there cannot be a compatible norm. Maybe from not being locally bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *not* a Banach space, as $d$ is no norm.
It is a locally convex completely metrisable TVS, also called a Fréchet space in this context.

It is certainly not compact as the constant functions from a non-compact closed copy of $\Bbb R$.

It *is* separable: can use (rational) polynomials to approximate continuous functions uniformly on some $[-N,N]$ for $N$ large enough..

Comment: Can you explain better the non-compactness argument? Thank you

Comment: @A.Pesare It's as I said: let $C$ be the the set of constant functions $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. It's homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ and closed in $C(\Bbb R, \Bbb R)$. So if the latter were compact, so would $C$ and hence $\Bbb R$ be. Contradiction.